# How do I install the Wix extension on after a Visual Studio 2013 Update?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wix

I have installed Wix 3.9 on VS 2012. Recently, I just got VS 2013 and I am not sure how to install just the extension on there?

How do I do without uninstalling wix 3.9 and reinstalling it back again?

Comment: Have you tried to do a repair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I in the end wasn't able to find a way to resolve this without uninstalling and installing WIX. Repair didn't resolve this issue.

I had to uninstall and install WIX again to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to the following link for downloading the package. I think you need to uninstall the old version and reinstall the downloaded one. But not completely sure.

download link : http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/610859